# What is the best way to redirect to another page after successful action in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to redirecting user after they successfully logged in by dispatching "AUTH_SUCCESS" action and gave me their tokens.There are several ways of doing this but I want your advise.Which one is the best way to redirect them after login? Whether using something in actions or in functional components.NOTE: I'm using functional components. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using `react-router` for your application routing, you could try `connected-react-router`: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router

Answer (score 0):

*Pseudocode*

For thunk just pass this.props.history in your login event

Front end somewhere..

```
login = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const creds = { username: username, password: password}
 this.props.login(creds, this.props.history);
}
```

**Thunk**

```
export const login = (credentials, history) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
     .....
    /// after successful
    history.push('/dashboard);
   }
}
```